# Windows Ubuntu servers VMs on the same server

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization

I'm trying to have a normal workstation (windows) and Ubuntu servers on the same computer.

The problem is that Ubuntu servers must not run on top of Windows (as a VirtualBox VM) for security reasons (not critical but need to be separated).

Devices like keyboard, mouse, monitor, etc (except network card) should be connected to Windows

I heard this was maybe possible with KVM and passthrough of devices to Windows.

To sum up something looking like that would be nice : 
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEqDQ.png)

What is the best way/tool to do this ?

Comment: A virtual machine.

Comment: Your diagram looks right. You just need to choose your hypervisor. But that's off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do. Are you running an ubuntu webserver off of a machine which is normally a windows workstation? That's not a good idea for a number of reasons but, if it is, you'll want to look at **Hyper-V** which is the Windows Hyperviser able to run Ubuntu and Linux servers etcetera. It may be pre-installed on your machine.

You may have problems with networking and all sorts of things, not to mention power stability and the user just switching the machine off.

**Maybe a better solution...**

I'm linux based though so someone else might know better here... You or your management might be looking at this backwards. It's possible to have windows desktops remotely and remote desktops are a good way to save on software licenses. You'd have a server running a hyperviser of your choice (lots support windows - even KVM iirc) and implement remote windows desktops for the workstations and run servers from some other VMs.

Even better might be to split your remote desktops (workstations) and server's physical hosts so that a ddos or an external doesn't stop everyone from working? :) This will obviously cost more but would be safer ;)

Comment: First, thanks for answering.
Actually I'm trying to have a windows 10 running in a vm at the same level as other Ubuntu servers.
But I'd like to have windows handling i/o devices and showing up when starting the monitors so we could use it normally. Ubuntu servers only need network access. Hyper-v or Vbox on the workstation is not suitable.
The whole thing should maybe look like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEqDQ.png

Comment: I see! :) 

What is your logic for the Hypervisor not being the Windows Machine with Hyper-V? I'm running a windows 10 desktop as I type this and Hyper-V is an option for me to run a Linux VM. 

It seems to me that your windows VM might be redundant when exactly what you want to achieve is it being host OS?

Comment: Also, you may want to look at [this](https://www.kraxel.org/blog/2016/04/linux-evdev-input-support-in-qemu-2-6/) which was recently included in Qemu. Starting at boot / showing as the monitor is probably very difficult though because the host OS would need to boot first... 

Interesting problem so I'm still interested to know why you wouldn't just run the windows machine as the hyperviser :)

Comment: I was afraid of some problems like rebooting/shutting down/messing up the workstation and so every of the linux VM but finally if I don't let my messy coworkers :) approach the computer having the windows workstation as host might be a solution